How to make behavior definition extension switchable in RAP?
We have created a behavior definition extension of an existing behavior definition.
We want to put this extension under switch, is there a way to do this in RAP?
We have created a behavior definition extension of an existing behavior definition.
We want to put this extension under switch, so that once the switch is ON, then only extension will be called, just like BADI implementation
